# Incorrect syntax near '@search'

Tags: c#

I did this code in visual studio 13, everything was great until I upload my website on aspspider I got this error, I searched  about this error and I tried everything but nothing change please help me

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    string str = "select * from [exp] where  Expression=@search  Order by Expression";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, conn)

    com.Parameters.Add(" @search", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    da.SelectCommand = com;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Expression");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the instantiation of `SqlCommand`, but see Soner's answer for a more complete solution.

Comment: @Caramiriel You are right as well but I think that missing `;` is just a typo since code wouldn't _even_ compile without it but OP gets a runtime error :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you *just* need to delete white space just before your parameter name.

```
com.Parameters.Add(" @search"
```

part should be

```
com.Parameters.Add("@search"
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and adapter automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConneciton(conStr))
using(var com = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   // Define your CommandText
   // Add your parameter values with Add method.

   using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
   {
       // Do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you ,but this isn't working too

Comment: @Bashaier What do you mean by _isn't working too_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
         
         DataTable ds = new DataTable();
       da.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: the error gone after i did it like this,
but when  i press button search  the result in the GridView dosn't appear ,any idea